# Changing title bar icon in Powershell script with embedded XAML GUI

Tags: powershell, xaml, icons

this is my first post. I'm writing a script launcher app in Powershell with embedded XAML code for the GUI. The XAML was roughed out in Visual Studio, then exported into Powershell and tweaked manually. Simple and maintainable, but I'm stuck trying to change the app's title bar icon. Changing the icon is an internal branding need.

The generic Powershell icon does appear in my app's title bar. And I think I've tried to adapt every XAML and code-behind technique mentioned on this site and elsewhere to install my own ICO icon. No joy. Some require using Visual Studio, which I'm hoping not to go back to. The simplest suggested XAML route seems to be adding a line like this...

```
Icon="MyFavicon.ico"
```

...below the Title line in the testbed below. But that throws this error:

```
Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "Failed to create a 'Icon' from the text 'StribLogoFavicon.ico'."
At M:\Scripting\Saxophone\Test\trivial_xaml_and_ps_for_icon_troubleshooting_v18.ps1:26 char:2
+     $Window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($Reader)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : XamlParseException

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At M:\Scripting\Saxophone\Test\trivial_xaml_and_ps_for_icon_troubleshooting_v18.ps1:28 char:1
+ $Window.ShowDialog()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

FWIW, the same ICO file worked previously in the the title bar of an HTA version of this project. I've also tried a second ICO file.

The location of the ICO file isn't critical for my deployment purposes. I've tried to script's root folder and a subfolder.

Here's my project's bare skeleton. Can anyone suggest a solution? Maybe we can use this testbed to document an easily confirmable one. Thanks!

```
#Trivial pared-down app GUI for icon troubleshooting
    Add-Type -AssemblyName presentationframework, presentationcore, windowsbase
    #Begin XAML code for GUI
    [xml]$xaml = @"
    <Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            x:Name="Demo_WPF_Window"
            Title="How to change icon at left?" Height="150" Width="320" WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow" Background="#FFECBD5A" ResizeMode="NoResize"
    >
        <Grid x:Name="Grid">
            <Grid Margin="18,64,0,18">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="126*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>
        <Label x:Name="Label_Icon_testbed" Content="Icon is ICO file in same folder as PS1 script" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="45" Margin="19,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="240" FontSize="11" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    </Grid>
   </Window>
"@
#Prepare the GUI
    $Reader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml
    $Window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($Reader)
#Render the GUI
    $Window.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get an Icon added by setting the icon in the Window Loaded event:

```
#region Load the Assemblies
Add-Type -assemblyName PresentationFramework
Add-Type -assemblyName PresentationCore
Add-Type -assemblyName WindowsBase
#endregion

#region XAML
[xml]$XAML = @"
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Testing" Height="200" Width="300" >

</Window>
"@
#endregion XAML

#Load the XAML and catch a failure
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 
try{$Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )}
catch{Write-Host "Unable to load Windows.Markup.XamlReader. Some possible causes for this problem include: .NET Framework is missing PowerShell must be launched with PowerShell -sta, invalid XAML code was encountered."; exit}

##XAML Should have loaded NOW

#Set all "Names" as Variables
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@*[contains(translate(name(.),'n','N'),'Name')]]") | ForEach-Object{
    Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $Window.FindName($_.Name)
}

#region EVENTS
$Window.add_Loaded({
    $Window.Icon = "C:\Path\to\Icon.ico"
})
#endregion EVENTS


##Show the Window - Wrap ShowDialog in the Async Dispatcher to prevent powershell from crashing on second run
$async = $window.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync({
    $window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
})
$async.Wait() | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Shamus' working answer -- much appreciated! -- integrated with the bottom portion of the testbed code above:

```
$Reader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml

$Window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($Reader)


$Window.add_Loaded({
    $Window.Icon = "C:\full\path\to\favicon.ico"
})

$Window.ShowDialog()
```